# Angular 2 typescript protected members in component templates

Tags: angular, typescript

I was thinking about how could be possible implement some members in a component that could be accessed from the template but not from a parent component.

I searched for some information about the typescript visibility in angular 2 but I only found topics about "public" and "private" declarations but not about"protected".

So, does it make sense to use "protected" for this?

Answer (score 24):

This feature is available in [Angular 14+](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v14-is-now-available-391a6db736af).

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '{{ message }}',  // Now compiles!
})
export class MyComponent {
  protected message: string = 'Hello world';
}
```

(this question still comes top of the Google results for 'angular protected member in template' so I thought it was worth updating)

Comment: Thank you JayChase, I wrote this question 5 years ago :) and I completely forgotten. For me is a very good feature for library developers. Thanks to the angular communityfor implementing it ^^

Answer (score 1):

the compiler warns me if i use in the html file a property which is declared private (although it works!). If i use protected, then no warns is emitted

Comment: using private variables in templates works in the dev environment, production builds will fail.

Answer (score 0):

> some members in a component that could be accessed from the template but not from a parent component.

`protected`/`private` only make sense if you are doing component inheritance. This is now the thing you are discussing. Component *composition*  doesn't impact your choice here.

Comment: For example, I have a View with 2 components, a field to create items and a list.
Both are managed by a parent component, when the user creates an item with the creator component, the component emits an event to the parent component, the parent component notify to the list component that a new item has been created.
My point is, the creator component has a "createItem" function that is triggered by the ui, so should be public, but if this function doesn't should be available to the parent component, make it protected makes the function available in the template but not for parent components?

Comment: this isn't true at all. it often makes sense to make a variable private or protected in a pluggable component that many developers will be using to make the interface of the component cleaner and more obvious. This is a standard approach.